# Gson deserialize field to variable with different name although having variable with the field name

Tags: java, gson, deserialization

I am getting a json from a server (not my server) that contains the key 'id'.
I want to deserialize it into a variable called 'jsonId' inside my object.
I used @SerializedName("id") to do it, but the problem is that my object also has variable called id, and because of that i get duplication error.

How can I map 'id' to the variable 'jsonId', while igonring the 'id' variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the field that is named `id` meant to be part of the serialized content at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options.

One option is to mark your field named `id` as `transient`. [Gson ignores any field modified with `transient`.](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

> If a field is marked transient, (by default) it is ignored and not included in the JSON serialization or deserialization.

Another option is to annotate the `jsonId` field (and all other relevant fields) with `@Expose` and build your `Gson` instance to exclude fields without the annotation. For example,

```
Gson mapper = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

Gson will now only deserialize those fields that are annotated with `@Expose`. It will not consider any others.